# How to make List report item repeat horizontally for RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, rdlc

I am using the `List` report item to make a report in visual studio with four report items per page. I am able to get the report to repeat vertically, but not horizontally. Is there a setting I am missing or do I need to do something additional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a horizontal [`List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx#Anchor_2) this way:

1. Insert a `List`
2. Right click on row header and from `Row Group` item, click `Delete Group`
3. Drag one or more fields from `Report Data` window, to data cell of report.
4. Right click on column header and from `Add Group` item in `Column Group` section click `Parent Group...`.
5. Enter `=RowNumber(Nothing)` as expression of group and click `OK`. (If you have a unique field like `Id`, you can choose it from dropdown and in such case you don't need to do step 6)
6. Again, right click on column header and from `Column Group` item, click `Group Properties...` and from `Sorting` tab, select first row in table and click `Delete`.

[image]

More settings on report:

- You can also perform this using a [`Table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx) or [`Matrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx)
- You can hide first row which shows record number.
- You can insert a column to show some row header.
- For more information take a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrishays/2004/07/23/horizontal-tables/) blog post about Horizontal Tables in SSRS.

Comment: THanks for sharing. How can you wrap the items at the right end of the parent rectangle?