# How to bind data to the columns in C# Windows Forms grid view, which are stored in rows in SQL table

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

Please refer the images. How to bind the SQL table data which are stored in rows in to data grid view (C# Windows Forms) as columns. Also I have created column[0] as a hard coded column. I need to bind these data which is coming from SQL to column[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIjWy.png). Please help me. Thanks in advance . :-)

[image: SQL Table]
[image: Expecting C# Grid View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method which rotate the `DataTable` and swap columns and rows this way:

```
public DataTable Rotate(DataTable table)
{
    var output = new DataTable();
    int i = 1;
    output.Columns.Add(" ");
    foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
        output.Columns.Add((i++).ToString());
    foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns)
    {
        var list = new List<object>();
        list.Add(c.ColumnName);
        var x = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => string.Format("{0}", r[c])).ToArray();
        list.AddRange(x);
        output.Rows.Add(list.ToArray());
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then you can use it to rotate the original table:

[image]

to rotated table:

[image]

or even with some simple tricks like this:

[image]

Here is the code which I used to create the example:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Rows.Add(100, "A", DateTime.Now);
dt.Rows.Add(200, "B", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
dt.Rows.Add(300, "C", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
dt.Rows.Add(400, "D", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = Rotate(dt);
//To hide column headers and show Id,Name,Date on rows headers, un-comment following codes:
//dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
//dataGridView2.Columns[0].Visible = false;
//for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
//    dataGridView2.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: Also if it's for reporting purpose, here is a solution for rdlc reports: [How to make List report item repeat horizontally for RDLC Report?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37623052/3110834)

Comment: It seems the post answers your question, let me know if you have any problem applying the solution or if you find it useful :)